# amCharts pie - how to get slice to pull out on rollOverSlice?

Tags: javascript, charts, amcharts

I am having a lot of difficulties navigating through amCharts Docs and I cant seem to find the answer to this online.

I am using the amCharts pie chart, and I want a couple of thing to happen when the mouse rolls over a slice, one of those things is to get the slice to pull out what happens when you click a slide in [this demo](http://www.amcharts.com/demos/donut-chart/).

This is what I tried according to the doc, but doesn't seem to work:

```
var pieChartData = [
    {
        asset: 'Funiture',
        marketValue: 50000.00
    }, {
        asset: 'Cash',
        marketValue: 6250.00
    }, {
        asset: 'Car',
        marketValue: 10000.00
    }, {
        asset: 'Other',
        marketValue: 11250.00
    }
];

    chartAsset = AmCharts.makeChart(
        'asset--chart', {
            type: 'pie',

            dataProvider: pieChartData,
            valueField: 'marketValue',
            titleField: 'asset',

            startEffect: 'easeOutSine',
            pulledField: 'pullOut',
            //pullOutOnlyOne: true,
            // pullOutEffect: 'easeInSine',

            responsive: {
              enabled: true
            },

            labelsEnabled: false,

            balloon: {
                fillAlpha: 0.95,
                borderThickness: 1,
                borderColor: '#000000',
                shadowAlpha: 0,
            }
        }
    );


    chartAsset.addListener('rollOverSlice', function(e) {
        console.log(e);

        /**** Doesn't work: ******/
        pieChartData[e.dataItem.index].pullOut = true;
        chartAssetAllocation.dataProvider = pieChartData;
        chartAssetAllocation.validateData(); 
    });
```

Can someone please help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not trigger the pullout directly, but there's a method to simulate the clicking on the slice. (see [clickSlice](http://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptcharts/AmPieChart#clickSlice))
In addition you have to add another listener for leaving a slice, so it will return to its original state.

```
    chartAsset.addListener('rollOverSlice', function(e) {
        chartAsset.clickSlice(e.dataItem.index);
    });

    chartAsset.addListener('rollOutSlice', function(e) {
        chartAsset.clickSlice(e.dataItem.index);
    });
```

Here's the working [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Lrktmwa5/).
Another approach would be to change just the visualization of the slice using CSS. An example for this can be found [here](http://www.amcharts.com/demos/pie-chart-with-legend/).

Comment: Hi gerric, your fiddle looks exactly like what I need, but I realize enabling responsive takes away the animation of the slice pulling out when you click on it. I might try to add in the affect via css animation like your second approach - thanks again!