# How to remove PullInSlice/PullOutSlice onclick and add PullInSlice/PullOutSlice on mouseover hover in Animated Amcharts Timeline Pie-chart

Tags: javascript, amcharts

I want to remove the slice pull in and pull out on Mouse Click on [Animated Amcharts Timeline Pie-chart](https://www.amcharts.com/demos/animated-time-line-pie-chart/)

Here is the code:

```
function pushvalue(curyear,curmonth,monvalue,state,statecount){
 array.push({year: curyear, month: curmonth, count: monvalue, state: state, 
 statecount: statecount});
}

var monthNames = ["January", "February","March", "April", "May", "June","July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December”];
var currentYear = 1997;
var array = [];

for (var i = 0; i < 4; ++i) {
for (var j = 0; j < 12; ++j) {
 pushvalue(currentYear + i, monthNames[j],count[j],state[j],statecount[j]);
}
}

var chartData = {};
for (var i = 0; i < array.length; ++i) {
 if (!chartData[array[i].year]) {
   chartData[array[i].year] = [];
 }
 chartData[array[i].year].push({"Month": array[i].month, "Count": array[i].count, “State”: array[i].state, “StateCount”: array[i].statecount });
}

var currentYear = 1997;
var chart = AmCharts.makeChart( "chartdiv", {
  "type": "pie",
  "theme": "light",
  "dataProvider": [],
  "valueField": "Count",
  “valueField1”: “State”,
  “valueField2”: “StateCount”,
  "titleField": "Month",
  "startDuration": 0,
  "innerRadius": 80,
  "pullOutRadius": 20,
  "marginTop": 30,
"balloonText": "Completed [[State]] for [[StateCount]] states in [[title]] month",
“labelText”: “[[title]] - [[value]]”,
  "titles": [{
    "text": "Test chart"
  }],
  "allLabels": [{
    "y": "54%",
    "align": "center",
    "size": 25,
    "bold": true,
    "text": "1995",
    "color": "#555"
  }, {
    "y": "49%",
    "align": "center",
    "size": 15,
    "text": "Year",
    "color": "#555"
  }],
  "listeners": [ {
    "event": "init",
    "method": function( e ) {
      var chart = e.chart;

  function getCurrentData() {
    var data = chartData[currentYear];
    currentYear++;
    if (currentYear > 2000)
      currentYear = 1997;
    return data;
  }

  function loop() {
    chart.allLabels[0].text = currentYear;
    var data = getCurrentData();
    chart.animateData( data, {
      duration: 1000,
      complete: function() {
        setTimeout( loop, 3000 );
      }
    } );
  }

  loop();
}
  } ],
    } );
```

Only answer I came across is [amCharts pie - how to get slice to pull out on rollOverSlice?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31156286/7115396)

But in that answer the Rolloverslice was just added to the actual clickonslice event predefined in the Amcharts.
Is there anyway to remove the clickonslice pulloutslice that predefined and add it on mouse hover over event? 
As we are planning to add some other event for Clickonslice.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The only way to disable slice pull out on click is to set [`pullOutRadius`](http://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptcharts/AmPieChart#pullOutRadius) to 0. Doing this prevents  the natual pull out from occuring even through calling `clickSlice`, so you'll have to leverage the CSS transform method described in the SO thread you linked to allow pull out on hover (you'll need to set [`addClassNames`](http://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptcharts/AmChart#addClassNames) to true first) along with setting the [`defs`](http://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptcharts/AmPieChart#defs) property to add some kind of pull out-like interactivity on hover (see AmCharts' [SVG filters](https://www.amcharts.com/kbase/svg-filters/) documentation on how to customize `defs`). Relevant code below:

```
 /* CSS */
.amcharts-pie-slice {
  transform: scale(1);
  transform-origin: 50% 50%;
  transition-duration: 0.3s;
  transition: all .3s ease-out;
  -webkit-transition: all .3s ease-out;
  -moz-transition: all .3s ease-out;
  -o-transition: all .3s ease-out;
  cursor: pointer;
  box-shadow: 0 0 30px 0 #000;
}

.amcharts-pie-slice:hover {
  transform: scale(1.1);
  filter: url(#shadow);
}

// ... in makeChart
  "defs": {
    "filter": [{
      "id": "shadow",
      "width": "200%",
      "height": "200%",
      "feOffset": {
        "result": "offOut",
        "in": "SourceAlpha",
        "dx": 0,
        "dy": 0
      },
      "feGaussianBlur": {
        "result": "blurOut",
        "in": "offOut",
        "stdDeviation": 5
      },
      "feBlend": {
        "in": "SourceGraphic",
        "in2": "blurOut",
        "mode": "normal"
      }
    }]
  },
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/9428r6fw/6/)